# The speed of expansion of space in big freeze

Tags: cosmology, spacetime, space-expansion, universe, dark-energy

In the case of big freeze, space expansion will be accelerating and there appears to be a lot of different phenomena occurring. However, in the case of big rip, the expansion is super-accelerating so that light speed will be reached, ripping apart every structure. How come this speed is not reached in the case of big freeze. If the speed of expansion is accelerating, it should reach light speed at some moment. How does the evolution of scale factor in this case look like?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What the "rate of expansion" means in this context is $da/dt$ where $a$ is the unitless scale factor. This has units of 1/time, not distance/time, so it can't be compared to the speed of light.

In a big rip, the rate of expansion goes to infinity at a finite time, not to $c$. In the big freeze of standard cosmology, the rate increases exponentially with time, but there is no special value of the rate at which anything else happens. The scale factor is only meaningful up to an arbitrary rescaling, so you can make the rate have any value at any time.

Answer (score 0):

In the case of heat death/big freeze, matter within galaxy groups (such as our own, comprising of the Milky Way and Andromeda) is gravitationally bound together, while the spaces in between are accelerating away, due to the effects of dark energy.

There's nothing in the model which stops the speed of expansion in between galaxy groups reaching the speed of light, but galaxy groups themselves will not be torn apart, as dark energy is not ''strong'' enough to override gravity.